# F# Finding the Missing element between 2 arrays/lists

Tags: arrays, list, f#, syntax-error, shuffle

`So, I am very new to F#. I hope the issue is simple. I have been doing research and looking around. I have an "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression" error. I feel like it might be something simple or I am way off.

The objective is:

There is an array of non negative integers. A second array is 
formed by shuffling the elements of the first 
array and deleting a random element. Given these two arrays, find which element is missing in the second 
array. Linear searching is not allowed.

```
let FindMiss list =
match list with
| [] ->
    []
|firstElem::otherElements ->
    let rand = new Random
    let shuffle (arr : 'a array) =
            let array = Array.copy arr
            let n = array.Length
            for x in 1..n do
                let i = n-x
                let j = rand.Next(i+1)
                let tmp = array.[i]
                array.[i] <- array.[j]
                array.[j] <- tmp
            array
    return array
    array.[rand].delete
|array::list ->
   let  d=collections.defaultdict(int)
   for num in list do
       d[num] +=1
   for num in array1 do 
        if d[num]==0 then return num 
        else d[num]-=1

printfn "The missing Number is: %A" (FindMiss[4;2;1;7;5;6;3;2])
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot going wrong here ; several things seems to be more Python than F# (or I missed some news) : `.delete` `defaultdict` `return array` (even though return exists too in F# but not like that) ; identation is off which doesn't help understanding what starts and ends where ; it could be nice to have the whole error message and at which point it was raised too

Comment: I was afraid that defaultdict was only python. The error message is being thrown at       "let shuffle (arr : 'a array) ="  which is line 7. I can find the other methods for .delete and it is my understanding that without the "return" in return array that it will just return. I mainly just threw the "return array" in there just to see if that would fix anything. But, the rest im still unsure of.

Comment: that's probably the `return array` (not sure without the exact indentation I can't test it) ; in F# you return the last expression of the function no need for return (like the `array` just above). I suggest you start by writing two separate functions ; one for shuffling and one which search the "difference" between two "containers". Also you tend to mix arrays and lists you should choose one and stick to it (in a first step).

Comment: Alright I am doing it in 2 seperate blocks now. I feel like I am getting much closer also because I found a much better way to do it. I just cannot find a remove method that I can use in an if statement.          For Example, if head = tail then remove head

Comment: @LinkHyrule - here is a hint - if you want to remove head, just return tail

Answer (score 1):

The task is to reimplement List.except?

If not, just use that 'except' then:

```
[1;2;3] |> List.except [1;2]
```

Or was the task "random removal of element in list"? Then this is "the answer": https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889972/5514938

Answer (score 0):

For a start, for more readability, you can take the shuffling and deleting a random element in a separate function. For arrays, they may look like this:

```
let Shuffle arr = 
    let rand = System.Random()
    arr |> Array.sortBy(fun _ -> rand.Next())

let RemoveRandom arr  = 
    let rand = System.Random()
    let lng = arr |> Array.length
    let index = rand.Next lng
    [|0..lng - 1 |] 
    |> Array.choose(fun x -> if x = index then None else Some(arr.[x]))
    |> Shuffle
```

Further define the search function:

```
let FindMiss arr1 arr2 = 
    let sum1 = arr1 |> Array.sum
    let sum2 = arr2 |> Array.sum
    sum1 - sum2
```

Example:

```
let first = [| 4;2;1;7;5;6;3;2 |]
first |> printfn "%A"
let second = first |> RemoveRandom
second |> printfn "%A"
FindMiss first second |> printfn "Missing value is %i"
```

Print:

```
[|4; 2; 1; 7; 5; 6; 3; 2|]
[|2; 2; 3; 7; 1; 5; 6|]
Missing value is 4
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/g6wKUX