# Why F#'s List type doesn't have a Remove function?

Tags: list, collections, f#

I don't understand why F#'s List has an [append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.append%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function (which returns another list, in an immutable-friendly way), but doesn't have a `remove` function (I'm particularly interested in one that would receive T as a parameter, not the index:int of it, so not `removeAt`).

Why is this exactly?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889961/f-insert-remove-item-from-list

Comment: yes, that's a question to know how to remove, but not asking why doesn't the BCL include it already

Comment: I meant to point to the answer from Tomas Petricek in the same thread, it's not the first one there.

Comment: Tomas talks about `removing an element at a specified index`, I don't need that, I want to remove an element without specifying an index (updated question)

Comment: Voted to close because the question asks "why", not "how". If you want to "how", there is a plenty of List module function that can help you as well as just a recursive solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889961/f-insert-remove-item-from-list

Comment: sometimes knowing the motivation of some decision from Microsoft can let you know what you're possibly doing wrong; so if there's no remove function maybe I shouldn't need it, but I want to know why there's no remove function first

Comment: completely agree, however stackoverflow is specifically about coding, not about reasoning about the design. Consider https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

"Why" in such cases is often "because no one implemented it". But in this case I would speculate that may be a design choice as well. Consider this:

- F# List is immutable, so a `remove` function would have to return a new list value.
- Unlike with a map and its `Map.remove key` or a set and `Set.remove item`, generally you don't assume that list elements will have equality, so including `List.remove` with equality constraint on the items would break that assumption.

Given this information, `List.remove` would only be an alias for `List.filter ((<>) item)` anyway, so you can use that instead.

Comment: the first element in your list of reasons seem to be a moot point, because `append` also returns a new list (because it's immutable, yes), as I already said in my question

Comment: I don't consider it moot, because I don't think `append` is a counterpart to `remove`. I think `add index item` would be, and it's also missing from the API. I used it to build up towards the `filter` function, which returns a new value, as opposed to destructive `ResizeArray.Remove` method

Comment: `add index item`? the question explicitly states not wanting to remove by index, but by item

Comment: @knocte `remove` would be able to remove from any place in the list. How would you model an opposite operation with the same power but without an index? The API isn't completely symmetrical, but IMO the meaning of `add index item` is a lot closer than `append list1 list2`

Answer (score 2):

This may seem taken for granted but why would you want to repeatedly remove item from a `List`? I mean if you want to remove it once you have `filter` but if you need to do it repeatedly then `List` is probably not the collection you should be using as performance would be horrible (`O(n^2)` complexity).
So I think it's good that `remove` is not provided on `List` so people don't wrongly pick the collection type they shall be using and this indirectly encourages people to know the hidden pros and cons for their collection choice. After all `List` in F# is a linked list rather than just an array wrapper in C#.

Comment: mmm, `removeAt` doesn't exist either, it exists in S.C.G.List, not in F#'s List