# insert and remove from muatble lists

Tags: f#

I want to write a function that inserts a value v into a list on postition a. the type of the list is

```
type RefList<'t> = Item<'t> ref
and Item<'t> = | Nil | Cons of 't * RefList<'t>

let rec insert<'t> (a: int) (v: <'t>) (structure: RefList<'t>): unit =
```

and

```
let rec remove<'t> (a: int) (structure: RefList<'t>): unit =
```

I tried something like this, but Im sure im on a very wrong way

```
let mutable worker = 0
     if a = worker then then Cons(v, !structure) else Cons(y, insert i v ys)
 worker <- worker + 1
```

im not sure if i should do a match to |Nil and |Cons or not. the "unit" confuses me.

I hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Edit: I already have a function RefListToList and ListToRefList. this might be useful for the other functions

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889961/f-insert-remove-item-from-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# insert/remove item from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889961/f-insert-remove-item-from-list)